# what is wrong with this IF satemenet

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is wrong with this statement. 
 **data** may contain any one of the following value :CheckBox, Radio-Button, Payment-Gateway, Message, Award.
If data is having any of the value then it should not execute if Block, But unfortunately it is.

```
    if (data != "CheckBox" || data != "Radio-Button" || data != "Payment-Gateway" || data != "Award" || data != "Message") {

                    DynamiccontrolType.className = "form-control";
                } 
else
{
//nothing should happen;
}
```

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: replace `!=` with `!==`

Comment: you'd need to be more specific than that.

Comment: data is variable containing value like checkbox etc

Comment: This if statement logically is equal to `true`. Your logic is flawed. What do you want to accomplish? When *should* the if be true?

Comment: what is in data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant solution :

```
if( ["CheckBox", "Radio-Button", "Payment-Gateway", "Message", "Award"].indexOf(data) == -1){
    // data isn't any of these words
} else {
    // data is one of these words
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this sol

Answer (score 2):

If the data is not "Value1" **OR** it is not "Value2" then

There is no value where this statement is false.

Use **AND** to connect the expressions

```
if (data != "CheckBox" && data != "Radio-Button" && data != "Payment-Gateway" && data != "Award" && data != "Message") {
     DynamiccontrolType.className = "form-control";
}
```

**Edit:**

if you want to use **OR** you have to negate the conditions (use `==` instead of `!=`)

```
if (data == "CheckBox" || data == "Radio-Button" || data == "Payment-Gateway" || data == "Award" || data == "Message") {
     DynamiccontrolType.className = "form-control";
}
```

Comment: data contains only one value at a time. so I need OR Statement

Comment: No you don't need. You have to compare it at on point in time, but you have to check several conditions. If you want OR statements, see me edit.

Comment: Thank you. Your sol. also works using == but I chose to use other

Answer (score 1):

This is an OR statement... anything different from Checkbox or the other words will pass... you should use && or ==, depending on the objective

Comment: data contains only one value at a time. so  I need OR Statement

Comment: @Asif You seem to fundamentally misunderstand a basic concept of programming. I suggest going back to basics with some tutorials.

Comment: @TZHX Please if you cant understand what the question is you should not interfere.

Comment: @Asif I understand what the question is, you, however, quite clearly didn't understand Andre's response.

Comment: @TZHX I understant it very clearly. it should pass if it contains value other that specified. That is the use of OR operator. Good Luck with your logic

Comment: @Asif I'm sorry, but if you understood the response and what the OR operation was achieving, you'd never have asked this question because you would have realised before going to the effort of posting it to the internet that it was fundamentally broken and would never have behaved as you wanted it to.

Comment: @TZHX sometimes brain doesn't  work, that is why stack overflow is here.